# Why is resolvectl no longer included in Bionic and what's the alternative

Tags: systemd, systemd-resolved

`resolvectl` is no longer part of the bionic `systemd` package:

[bionic search for resolvectl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=resolvectl)

[cosmic search for resolvectl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=resolvectl)

I'm curious why it was removed and what we should be using as an alternative?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`resolvectl` was never part of the `systemd` package in Bionic. Per the [systemd changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/NEWS#L7942), `systemd-resolve` was renamed to `resolvectl` in systemd 239, but Bionic has systemd 237. Thus in Bionic it is `systemd-resolve`.

Comment: I was confused about the release names. cosmic is actually after bionic... [sigh]

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a bit different from `systemd-resolve` (please check [man `resolvectl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/resolvectl.1.html))

```sh
# Reset interface dns settings
sudo resolvectl revert your_interface

# Sets your_dns_ip on a your_interface
sudo resolvectl dns your_interface your_dns_ip

# Sets your_domain_name on a your_interface
sudo resolvectl domain your_interface your_domain_name

# Check
sudo resolvectl dns
sudo resolvectl domain
```