# systemd-resolve command not found in Ubuntu 22.04 desktop

Tags: 22.04, systemd-resolved

I am going through some tutorials. When I try to execute `systemd-resolve --status` in Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, the system reports command is not found. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried running `sudo apt-get install -y systemd` but it seems like **systemd-resolve** is not installed. Please help.

Comment: Please try: `sudo service systemd-resolved status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 The systemd-resolve used to be a command in former Ubuntu versions. It's not the deamon systemd-resolved.  Apparently it got removed, or left out.

Comment: @ubfan1 It works perfectly well on my fully updated 22.04 system.

Comment: @chili555 your command only shows the status of the currently running systemd-resolved service - which shows process info and recent log output.  This is not the same thing as the output from resolvectl status (or systemd-resolved --status in prior ubuntu version).  "resolvectl status" outputs nameserver information and other configuration information that isn't available in the service output.

Answer (score 94):

Use `resolvectl status` instead.

In systemd 239 `systemd-resolve` has been renamed to `resolvectl` (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1149374/900737)).

For the most part `resolvectl` offers the same options as `systemd-resolve`, though they may be named slightly differently.
Run `resolvectl --help` to find what you are looking for.

Comment: It's not a 1:1 replacement though.  There's no --set-dns option that was available on systemd-resolve.

Answer (score 15):

Here I updated ubuntu to 22.04 and my VPN stopped working. I fixed it with: `sudo ln /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/bin/systemd-resolve`

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem (Ubuntu server 22.04 )!

Comment: this works thanks!

Comment: +1 I would suggest to do a symbolic link instead with `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/bin/systemd-resolve`. This is more transparant as `ls -l /usr/bin/systemd-resolve` will show that is is only a link to `/usr/bin/resolvectl`

Answer (score -2):

First try these commands:

```
systemctl status
```

or

```
sudo service --status-all
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve or address anything because it has no relevance to the fact that systemd-resolve was renamed, as pointed out in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1410472/587804