# How to flush the DNS cache in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking, dns, 22.04

How to clear the DNS cache in Ubuntu 22.04?

I tried the solution given "for 17.04 and higher" from [How do I clear the DNS cache?](https://askubuntu.com/a/929478) but it did not work (command not found):

```
{19:58}~ ➭ tail -n1 /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
{19:58}~ ➭ sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
sudo: systemd-resolve: Befehl nicht gefunden
```

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410472/569424) to a related question gives a hint, so that the answer to the above question is:

```
resolvectl flush-caches
```